# Gnuplot heatmap interpolation with svg

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a heatmap using gnuplot (5.2.8) with the SVG terminal.
Gnuplot interpolates the colors between the center points of the cells.

When I use the pdf terminal the result is as expected and the cells are clear and uniform faces.
How do I turn the interpolation for the SVG terminal off?

```
#set terminal svg size 600,600
set terminal pdf size 600,600
set style line 12 lc rgb '#ffffff' lt 1 lw 5
set border front 15 ls 12
set grid front ls 12

set datafile separator ','

percent_sample(sample) = sprintf("sample_%d/configuration.csv", sample)

set palette defined (0  '#c00000', 1 '#0000cc') model RGB
unset colorbox

#set cbrange[0:1]

set xrange [-0.5:9.5]
set yrange [-0.5:9.5]

unset key

set tics scale 0

unset xlabel
set xtics 0.5,1

unset ylabel
set ytics 0.5,1

set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0

#set view map


set output sprintf("sample_conf_%d.pdf", i)
plot percent_sample(i) matrix  with image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not gnuplot that does the interpolation - it is the SVG viewing program.  Leaving aside the question of how you might persuade the viewer not to do this, you can prevent it from happening by using the keyword `pixels` in the gnuplot command:

```
plot percent_sample(i) matrix with image pixels
```

This tells the program to describe each pixel in the output image as a separate rectangle rather than merging them into a stream of contiguous pixels.  See also:

[heatmaps demo](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_5.2/heatmaps.html)